# Including external libraries to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake

I am actually new at Qt and would be grateful if someone could explain how to deal with external C++ libraries in theses 3 cases and what is the easiest way to get a library working with Qt (if you could just point me out to some places where I can read about it):
- source .h and header .cpp files both available
- source .h and DLL
- source .h and .a files

I usually use the following procedure:
1- Cmake to generate make files
2- Building using Mingw:

```
 Cd c:/test
 qmake test.pro
 mingw32-make
```

3- Including project to Qt:

```
 INCLUDEPATH += C:/test/build/include
 LIBS += C:\test\build\x64\mingw\lib\file.dll.a \ ...
```

I usually use Cmake first then qmake to build, but sometimes one is not working or often Qt option is not available in Cmake. I always read carefully the instructions. In general, how an experience programmer would make decisions on how to include a library?

Comment: Cmake is professional tool and I recommend you use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need `cmake` and `qmake` together -- One is enough. I mainly work with `qmake` when i'm in `Qt Creator` since it is well integrated with the IDE. Generally what you are doing is correct. You include headers under `HEADERS +=`, sources under `SOURCES +=`, libraries under `LIBS +=` and the path to the include files under `INCLUDEPATH +=`.

Comment: Thanks GradGuy, to be honest, I am a bit confused about what will do what (I am still looking for that info and it is actually not easy to find!). Is qmake only for including libraries with .lib files? what if I only had .h and .cpp files?

Comment: If you have a library like, say `libfoo.a`, you need to do:
`LIBS += -L/path/to/lib -lfoo`. If, on the other hand, you just want to include a couple of `.h` and `.cpp` files in the project you do:
`HEADERS += /path/to/foo.h` and `SOURCES += /path/to/foo.cpp`. Depending on the files, you might, or might not, need to have `INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/header/library/files`. Hope that helps. Also you might want to have a look at this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html

Comment: You made my day GradGuy, wish I could vote up :) I'll whenever I get my 15. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of manually adding the external library to the .pro file u can do one thing.

Right click on your main project, then select "add library" option then it will ask for

```
1. External library
2. Internal Library
3. System Library
```

then select External library , and rest all thing is done by the Qt Creator i.e it will automatically add the path to the .pro file and link the library to your project.

Comment: Thanks Shobi, very clear, but could you tell how can I include a library when I only have the .h and .cpp files? Is it by simply #include "../files.h"? and why some libraries needs to be build in order to use them rather than simply use the .h and .cpp files?